# Openstack, a small image for a tiny flavor

Tags: openstack, devstack

Recently I installed openstack using devstack on my laptop. The problem I'm facing is to launch an instance, since my pc have poor ressources (32 bits, 4 Go Ram, 20Go free space), I need to deploy a very small image.

I tried an iso image for an ubuntu, I downloaded also a image from Ubuntu Cloud images but both of them can't be started. All I want to do is to launch an `instance`, `install java`, `Tomcat server`.

Any advice about an image that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Ubuntu Server Cloud Image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/)

It will run perfectly with 512 MB of RAM.

Also stop unwanted services to save memory. Like stop ssh, sendmail, crond If you are not using them.

Answer (score 0):

devstack has cirros built-in. It is probably as small as you can get. It is a limited distro, but you should be able to download the jdk installer and run it.

You may need to download a 32 bit cirros image. The cirros distro downloads are available here:
https://launchpad.net/cirros/+milestone/0.3.0

This image should work for you:
https://launchpad.net/cirros/trunk/0.3.0/+download/cirros-0.3.0-i386-disk.img

Comment: thank's for the help, I tried cirros but I have this error Booting from rom this kernel require an x86-64 cpu, but only detected an i 686 cpu unable to boot

Comment: Updated my answer with links to the 32 bit version of cirros.

Answer (score 0):

Use ubuntu cloud images. Make sure your cloud image is also 32bit.

While spawning instance, see that you look into Nova Security groups to allow ports which you might use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any image which are at **https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/obtain-images.html.

In these `Ubuntu` image is one which you can use and install applications on it.
It comes with default username `ubuntu` and you can set new password using `cloud-init` of heat template or manually while launching the instance.